# flutter: Google sign-in error: PlatformException(google_sign_in, No active configuration. Make sure GIDClientID is set in Info.plist

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase, google-signin

this is my auth class

```
class Authentication {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

  
  Future<User?> signInWithGoogle() async {
    try {
      final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
      if (googleUser == null) {
        // User canceled the sign-in process
        print('User canceled Google Sign-In.');
        return null; // Return null to indicate cancellation
      }

      final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
          await googleUser.authentication;

      final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
        idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
      );

      final UserCredential userCredential =
          await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);

      return userCredential.user;
    } catch (e) {
      print('Google sign-in error: $e');
      return null;
    }
  }
  Future<void> signOutGoogle() async {
    await googleSignIn.signOut();
    print("Google user signed out");
  }
}
```

this is how its called inside a gesturedetector ontap

```
   Authentication auth = Authentication();
    User? user = await auth.signInWithGoogle();
```

And as soon as it gets clicked the **App Crashes(iOS Simulator iPhone 15)**
and gives this error

**flutter: Google sign-in error: PlatformException(google_sign_in, No active configuration.  Make sure GIDClientID is set in Info.plist., NSInvalidArgumentException, null)
Lost connection to device.
Exited.**

It was working fine for past 3 weeks and out of nowhere this error popped up idk how to handle this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the client ID from the GoogleService-Info.plist into your app's [my_project]/ios/Runner/Info.plist file.

```
<key>GIDClientID</key>
<string>Copied from GoogleService-Info.plist key IOS CLIENT ID</string>
```

For more information visit the docs: https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in_ios